# Is there a way to test out the mist browser from a website without downloading it?

Tags: mist

I want to test out the mist browser by going to a website without the need to download it and install it. Is there such an implementation? A testnet setup with some test coins would be good.

Comment: if i understood you are seeking for an online Mist 'like the web proxy', I think such thing is unavailable.  only solidity browser is available online.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking for, [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) [browser-solidity](/questions/tagged/browser-solidity) or [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) [metamask](/questions/tagged/metamask) might help.  Browser-solidity is primarily for writing smart contracts; MetaMask is for using DApps without needing to install Mist.

Generally, you won't find a website that allows you to try a browser (like Mist, Firefox, etc), without downloading the browser.